# Sorting data frames by columns in r

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a dataframe by column(s) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r)

I am trying to sort a data.frame by several columns

```
df<-data.frame("Sp1"=c(7,4,2),"Sp2"=c(6,2,1))
row.names(df)<-c("A01","A02","A03")

    Sp1 Sp2
A01   7   6
A02   4   2
A03   2   1

#I am using    

df[with(df, order("Sp1"))]
```

however this does nothing. Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: You should use library(plyr)  and the command - arrange(df, Sp1, Sp2)  . Easy to remember and fast too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Sp1` should not be quoted when you are using `with`. This would always just return `1` and thus just return your first row. Try this instead:

```
> df[order(df$Sp1),] 
    Sp1 Sp2
A03   2   1
A02   4   2
A01   7   6
> df[with(df, order(Sp1)), ]
    Sp1 Sp2
A03   2   1
A02   4   2
A01   7   6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use another bult-in function within `doBy` package:

```
# install.packages('doBy')
library(doBy)
orderBy(Sp1~Sp2, data=df)
    Sp1 Sp2
A03   2   1
A02   4   2
A01   7   6
```